What happens with phone with no SD storage (only GoogleDrive) when you don't have cellphone/internet signal? And how much data does transfer takes?
I have a S8 android phone with microSD card where all my pictures are stored. Now I need to change phone, and I've just learned the recent phones don't have microSD slot and all goes to Cloud Storage like Google Drive.
Except... Isn't Google Drive limited by, among other things, your capacity to access the Internet? What happens if you take a lot of pictures or videos somewhere where you don't have signal/internet reception? Does it not save the pictures or the videos? Furthermore, does the transfer of videos eat all of your data when you get signal back? Does it slow down the phone if you have shitty reception and you get off-on when it's trying to upload?
The sellers in mobile shops were just able to answer 'It works.' and I need a bit more specifics...
For information, I often need to go to places with no phone signal, that's why I have concerns.

Sorry, what what you have learned is wrong. There are still a lot of phone with Micro-SD card slots (so you want to continue using a micro-sd card you just have to chose the correct model). But many users don't need a micro-SD card anymore as the built-in flash memory is large enough (e.g. 128GB) and all files are stored there. If you upload it to cloud is your choice and is independent of the micro-sd card or the flash storage size.

Thank you for correcting what has been told to me, I appreciate it. I will look at further model than what's been offered in the mobile shops.

As Robert points out, phones are still available with micro-SD card slots.  You have to select the right model from your favourite manufacturer.  It often costs a little bit more.
You will also find that

Some phones come with only one slot for the SIM card.
Some phones come with two slots for SIM cards and the second slot can be used for a micro-SD card instead.
Some phones come with two slots, one is for the SIM and the other one can only be used for a micro-SD card.

You mention that you have an S8.  I only use Samsung phones and the above is true for their offerings.
